# Using jQuery to get the data of a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, web

I am new to jQuery and JSON. I have the following PHP code (getData.php) performs query from the database:

```
<?php
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     ....
     // some code here
     ....
     $my_arr=array();
     // fectching data into array
     while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
       // convert to integer value if there is a bug after passing json_encode
       $rev=intval($info['bIRevNum']);
       $name=$info['bIName'];
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $info['bName'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $info['bRevNum'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $info['bIName'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $info['bIRevNum'] . "</td>";
       $my_arr[]=array('br'=>$name,'rev'=>$rev);
       echo "<td>" . $info['pName'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $info['pRevNum'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }

     // json encode
     echo json_encode($my_arr);
?>
```

After use echo 'json_encode' here I can see the JSON object under this format
`[{"br":"itemsb1","rev":37},{"br":"itemb2","rev":45}]` on my page.

Now I want to access the integer of `rev` element of the object (37 and 45) for future usage by jQuery in a different PHP file, lets call it `index.php` and with the below script

```
<html>
.....
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
           $.getJSON("getData.php", function(obj) {
             $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                    $("#div1").append("<li>"+value.rev+"</li>");
         });
       });
   });

    });
</script>   
...
// test here
<!---jquery--->
<div id="div1"><h2>CHANGE >>>> ....!!!!</h2></div>
<button>Calling from different PHP file</button>
</html>
```

If it is correct, when I click on the button "Calling from different PHP file" it should appears the value of JSON object as 37, 45.

I have tried many ways, but it does not display anything on my page.

Please help me with this!

Comment: Use the developer console to track the AJAX call. Are you echo'ing the HTML (`"<td>" . $info['bName'] . "</td>"` etc.) in addition to the JSON?

Comment: only the json string can be sent, you are sending html also, this won't validate and will cause parserror

Comment: @kingkero yes that just additional stuff that i want to display on the page. I thought it would not affect when I use jquery to get the value. I did comment out those echo'ing HTML, but its still not working

Comment: @charlietfl I just try to test the output that why i am using echo HTML to display the data, so when I comment out, it does not change anything

Comment: my jquery script is not correct implemented?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your problem is that you are echo'ing the html as well as the JSON. try removing the 'echo' from these lines

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $info['bName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['bRevNum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['bIName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['bIRevNum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['pName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['pRevNum'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

**DO NOT** delete this line:

```
$my_arr[]=array('br'=>$name,'rev'=>$rev);
```

Also make sure your javascript is syntax correct

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.getJSON("getData.php", function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            $("#div1").append("<li>"+value.rev+"</li>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the only thing appear on my page is the json object [{"br":"itemsb1","rev":37},{"br":"itemb2","rev":45}]

Comment: @user3063604 and what does your developer console say? It will either have a JS error, or a network error (check the Network tab of your browser's dev console to see exactly what the AJAX request returned)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the only content coming back from getData.php is JSON-formatted; otherwise, it won't be parsed correctly.  If you visit getData.php in your browser directly, you should only see JSON content, and nothing else (including errors, warnings, etc.). Your jQuery looks good;  so the issue would have to be whatever content is coming back from the PHP script. I just whipped up a trivial test case using this PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $my_arr[]=array('br'=>'something','rev'=>'2.0.5');
    echo json_encode($my_arr);
?>
```

Using the exact HTML you provided, that works just as expected.

Comment: cool ! I know what happen now, the content coming back from my PHP script is not correct because the use of AJAX to interact with my database when doing query.. Thanks a lot this really helpful